# Перенос паролей из Chrome в систему Mac OS

Tags: google-chrome, macos

Можно ли как-то перенести пароли из `Chrome` в саму систему `Mac OS`?

Раньше пользовался `Windows` и все пароли хранились там. Теперь они перенеслись в `Chrome` для `Mac`, но они не переносятся в саму систему для использования другими браузерами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Такая возможность была удалена начиная с 45 версии Chrome.

Источник:https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58871/how-to-tell-google-chrome-to-use-my-keychain

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант импортировать в `.csv` , а после залить в какой нибудь менеджер паролей типа `LastPass` или `1Password`.

Answer (score 0):

Работает в Mojave 10.14 на Safari 13

Сначала нужно сохранить пароли в виде csv
Все строки должны быть в формате:

site.com,login123,pass123

Затем с помощью скрипта можно сохранить в Safari

Код работающего скрипта (на GitHub код устарел):

```js
-- select the csv to import to iCloud keychain
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file")

-- read csv file
set f to read theFile

-- split lines into records
set recs to paragraphs of f

-- open safari passwords screen, check it is unlocked, do not allow to proceed until it is unlocked or user clicks cancel.
tell application "System Events"
 tell application process "Safari"
  set frontmost to true
  keystroke "," using command down
  tell window 1
   click button "Passwords" of toolbar 1 of it
   repeat until (exists button "Add" of group 1 of group 1 of it)
    if not (exists button "Add" of group 1 of group 1 of it) then
     display dialog "To begin importing, unlock Safari passwords then click OK. Please do not use your computer until the process has completed." with title "CSV to iCloud Keychain"
    end if
   end repeat
  end tell
 end tell
end tell

-- getting values for each record
set vals to {}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
repeat with i from 1 to length of recs
 set end of vals to text items of (item i of recs)
 set kcURL to text item 1 of (item i of recs)
 set kcUsername to text item 2 of (item i of recs)
 set kcPassword to text item 3 of (item i of recs)
 
 -- write kcURL, kcUsername and kcPassword into text fields of safari passwords
 tell application "System Events"
  tell application process "Safari"
   set frontmost to true
   tell window 1
    
    click button "Add" of group 1 of group 1 of it
    -- write fields
    tell sheet 1 of it
     set value of text field 1 of it to kcURL
     keystroke tab
     set value of text field 2 of it to kcUsername
     keystroke tab
     set value of text field 3 of it to kcPassword
     keystroke return     
    end tell
    
   end tell
  end tell
 end tell
end repeat
```

Источник здесь:
https://github.com/PaperKup/csv-toicloudkeychain

Единственное, что Safari блокирует список паролей после вставленных примерно 50 паролей. Нужно из csv удалить, то что уже добавлено. И запустить скрипт еще раз.

Пока что это единственный рабочий вариант. Другого не нашел.